# Python + Scrapy + JSON : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all the urls from this JSON page with Scrapy in Python:

view-source:https://highape.com/bangalore/all-events

But whenever I write this code on my Scrapy shell:

```
import json #it works

jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'
```

This is a portion of that big json file:

```
{ 
        "@context":"http://schema.org",
        "@type":"Event",
        "name":"Combo Offers at Fill n Chill",
        "image":"https://highape.com/images/https://res.cloudinary.com/https-highape-com/image/upload/v1536231551/yyfdntyzgsuuctlrqw94.jpg",
        "url":"https://highape.com/bangalore/events/combo-offers-at-fill-n-chill-QRkdny0WXv",
        "startDate":"2018-09-07 12:00:00",
        "endDate":"2018-10-31 00:00:00",
        "doorTime":"2018-09-07 12:00:00",
        "description" : "Good food and fine drink are among the finer things life has to offer Fill n Chill has recognized this and therefore brings to you several offers packaged with scrumptious food and plenty of alcohol to wash it down Take a look at this and decide how you want to splurge and indulge1 Individual PassINR 349 2 Mugs of Beer 330ml 2 Domestic Drinks 30ml 1 StarterChoices belowBeer Draught Beer KingfisherDomestic Drinks Mixer Inclusions Served with Water SodaRum Captain Morgan Old MonkVodka Romanov Magi",
        "location":
        {"@type":"Place",

        "name":"Fill &#039;n Chill",

        "address":"107/2, 80 Feet Road, Srinivagilu Main Rd, Koramangala 4th Block, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560034, India"  
        },


                "offers":
        [
                                            { 
                    "@type":"Offer",
                    "name":"Individual Pass - 2 Drinks+1 Food",
                    "price":"349",
                    "priceCurrency":"INR",
                    "validFrom":"2018-09-06 12:52:28",
                    "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "url":"https://highape.com/bangalore/events/combo-offers-at-fill-n-chill-QRkdny0WXv"
                }, 
                                                            { 
                    "@type":"Offer",
                    "name":"Pass for 2 people - 4 Drinks +1 Food",
                    "price":"499",
                    "priceCurrency":"INR",
                    "validFrom":"2018-09-06 12:52:28",
                    "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "url":"https://highape.com/bangalore/events/combo-offers-at-fill-n-chill-QRkdny0WXv"
                }, 
                                                            { 
                    "@type":"Offer",
                    "name":"Pass for 2 people - 4 Drinks + 2 Food",
                    "price":"599",
                    "priceCurrency":"INR",
                    "validFrom":"2018-09-06 12:52:28",
                    "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "url":"https://highape.com/bangalore/events/combo-offers-at-fill-n-chill-QRkdny0WXv"
                }, 
                                {
                    "@type":"Offer",
                    "name":"Entry",
                    "price":"0",
                    "priceCurrency":"INR",
                    "validFrom":"2018-09-06 12:52:28",
                    "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "url":"https://highape.com"
                }     
                                    ]
      ,
                    "performer":
        [
          { "@type":"Person",
            "name": ""
          }    
        ] 
    }
```

I need to scrape URLs  like this (it would be quite helpful if you suggest a solution without involving Beautiful Soup) :

```
 "url":"https://highape.com/bangalore/events/combo-offers-at-fill-n-chill-QRkdny0WXv"
```

Comment: `response` doesn't have a value. How is it populated?

Comment: Try `response.text` or `response.body`

Comment: You're essentially trying to load the whole HTML doc into a json obj, and that's not going to work because of the formatting. You need to select the target json with xpath and then load that into json once it's been correctly extracted.